# What is and how to use PS1 \#

Tags: bash, prompt

I put this is .bashrc

```
# colors
NC="$(tput sgr0)"
RED="$(tput setaf 1)"
GREEN="$(tput setaf 2)"
# etc ...

PS1="\[$BROWN\]\u \[$CYAN\]#\# \[$PINK_BLD\]!\!\[$NC\] \[$BLUE\]\W: \[$NC\]"
```

So

```
deepo #50 !545 ~: echo "This is an example what it will look like."
```

What is, and how do I use, the hash 50 indication?

There are many pages on how to do the PS1 (e.g., http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) but from fast searches of those I get only standard descriptions of the hash thing (in this case, "the command number of this command").

Comment: I'm not sure what else you're looking for. It's the current command number. You'll see it increasing by one each time you type a new command.

Comment: @Mat I think he wants to know why it is useful. For the history number `\!` is see good use, but for the command number?

Comment: AFAICT from a quick perusal through the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html), the command number is only used by the `fc` built-in.

Comment: Yes, I assumed it could be used somehow. I never use fc, but who knows? Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
\#
```

stands for the current command number.